# Can I use a grow room air extractor as a dust collector?

Tags: dust-collection

I have an air extractor that I used for a grow room and was wondering if I could convert it into a dust collector for the shop.

This is the extractor:
https://ventilation-system.com/product/vk-200#characteristic

It is rated for 780m^3/h (459 CFM).

I also have a couple of big 200L (50 gallon) drums and several meters of soft ducting (the silver corrugated type)

I want to hang the extractor from the 3,5m (11.5ft) ceiling and run ductwork down the wall to a 200L (50 gallon) drum (used as a separator), and from there run a flexible hose that I can hook up to different tools as I use them.

Despite the shop's 38 m^2 (409 sq ft) area, I only produce dust in a small section, so I don't really need complicated duct work running to lots of areas.

Is my air extractor suitable for dust collection with this setup or any other setup?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This needs an edit to give the relevant details up front. As it is it's paragraph five before we get to the information that gives a prospective respondent the info they need to begin to formulate an Answer. While you're doing that I suggest you pare back to give only the information that's directly relevant to the basic query you have.

Comment: Now that aside I don't think this is a good fit for the SE format. What you're seeking to build could probably do with some spitballing, tossing a few ideas back and forth and that's what regular threaded forums are built for, rather than a strict Q&A venue which seeks to give canonical answers to a central query.

Comment: This might be the right place to drop this: https://youtu.be/bwA1P4H_3ys (In short, there are considerations to be made about what "extractors" do vs. what "collectors" do, and how they interact with all the hoses you think you are going to run stuff through. To answer your actual question you will need to know CFMs and other air-flow details or no one can help you.)

Comment: Agree that this is an idea "shopping" thread rather than something suitable for question-and-answer format. So, unless this can be edited down to a single question ("will this CFM system run through X-inch hose be suitable for XXX use?") then I am voting to close.

Comment: I'm familiar with Stumpy Nubs and had already watched that, twice. Thanks anyway for taking the time.

As for the 'actual' question, I think it's pretty clear (it's actually written down), despite being wrapped up in some context. (using this extractor and those drums could I build something).
CFM are 480, it was on the data sheet of the product, but in metric.
(Air)Extractor+Drum+Cyclone+Ducts = Collector

Comment: @RoTrad I've edited your question to try to focus on the thing you seem to be asking about rather than where you have a roof, your plans for planting grass, etc. Feel free to revert my edit if you think I've changed the meaning of your post, but be aware that SE groups like this one aren't discussion forums like others you might use; we expect people to take the time to write clear, specific questions that are objectively answerable. Read https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for helpful tips.

Comment: What the hell?? We were trying to help you, to the point of suggesting a *better* venue for seeking the kind of input this sort of project tends to need (or at least benefit from). I don't know why that struck you as in some way **un**helpful but I respectfully suggest you re-read to see the intent behind the Comments as not in any way a put-down, or whatever it was you inferred.

Comment: @RoTrad welcome! As other longtime members have already mentioned, your original question was not sufficiently focused and omitted critical details. You should not take offense to suggestions to help you improve your questions--it is to everyone's benefit if your question is written such that it is helpful to future visitors, as well as you. Also, if details only exist on an external page that is later removed , your question will no longer be helpful. Caleb's edits and the additional CFM conversion and rating you added in a comment are helpful. I'll make another edit and reopen the question.

Comment: Also, to me it's unclear what you mean by "soft ducting (the silver corrugated one)". If you have further questions about whether that type of ducting is appropriate for use in a dust collection system, please open a separate question with more details such as the thickness or gauge of the ducting, and ideally one or more pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Caleb, it's fine, I don't believe it hurts what I was going for.
It's true, I might be used to another kind of Q&A sites, I very rarely go on forums anyway.
Also, I always believe that context matters.

I read a bit of the how to ask page and OK, regardless of my opinion, this place operates under different rules, and that's fine.

Rob, no offense taken.
If you watch any video about indoor growing you'll see the duct I'm refering to, it's similar to that of the exaust of your dryer. Probably not suitable for dust collection as it has waves that

Comment: will both catch dust and particles and will significantly reduce the air flow. I'll probably use some in the corners but I was going to use PVC pipes as the mains. As I mentioned before, I won't be building a big elaborate duct system, maybe 12 mts (39ft) overall.
The extractor has a 200mm (8") inlet/outlet that will probably be reduced to a 100mm (4") PVC pipe (I have a few mts on hand so after testing I'll know how that reductions actually affects performance.)

Comment: Related: https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/a/3218/49

Answer (score 1):

The size of the fan you refer to is about right for a small (single machine) dust collector.    Most home shop machines require 600 or so m^3/hr flow.   A thickness planer could easily require 1000.   Your machine is rated at just under 900.

So, it could provide the air flow source.   Your task then would be to build an adequately sized cyclone, collection, and air filtration system.   Certainly doable, but I'm not certain you'd save much over buying a similarly sized dust extractor straight up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Great to know that the mt3/h is right, I guess I'll just have to build something up and try and take it from there.

How much could I save? I'd say quite a bit! I live in Chile and things here are pretty expensive, specially specific equipment such a dust colection system.
The cheapest one I found was about us$600, it features a 75lt bag and is 1150 mt3/h.
Since I already have the extractor and a 120lt drum, and a 3D printer, I only have to buy some ducts and I don't think that I'd spend more than us$50, call it us$100 just to be sure. 
So thank you!!!